# Receiving notifications from a remote machine as a local event

Tags: linux

What I want to achieve is to receive different notifications from a remote machine over ssh. For example when the long running job has finished.

One way is to send an message over xmpp, and have a jid client on a local machine. I want to do that without any intermediate server. I want to get this notifications via native system notification mechanism, so when the event raises I get a system popup, like the one I get using:

```
echo 'message:hi' | zenity --notification --listen
```

Or:

```
notify-send subject message
```

These work locally, but not with the remote session off course.

I am not available from network for a server I am connecting so it can't connect back to be over SSH and run `notify-send` command.

So I am trying trying to solve this by forwarding local port to a remote machine and writing a small server/client app. Client will send a message to a forwarded port and server on my machine will call `notify send` with the received message as an argument. But that looks like a wheel reinvention but I could not find a solution. Maybe it's possible to achieve with DBUS configuration.

Comment: What's wrong with syslog?

Comment: @yoonix Well I can't imagine a way of sending logs to the syslog on my local machone when a specific event happens aand triggering local `notify-send` afterwards after that specific event. Not all the things going in syslog. An example would helpful.

Comment: That's what logger is for.  `man logger`

Answer (score 1):

Assume (just because logging is a common practice) your application (on remote server) writes each event in a file. So each new line in that file is a desired notification. The trick:

`ssh my.remote.server 'tail -f /path/to/notifications/log' | while read line; do notify-send 'Server says' "$line"; done`

So once new line will appear in the log on the server you will see popup on local desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Put an mqtt broker on the remote, or on a third machine if you want. Publish the event from the remote to the broker. On the local, subscribe to the event topic via the broker. The local could be running something that invokes notify-send.

The mosquitto package comes with command-line programs for publish and subscribe so you can try this out in that way. Installing the package installs a broker if I recall correctly.

Comment: This might sound complicated but its actually quite clean and sensible. Start a mosquitto container on the remote (or a third server), run this script on your desktop https://github.com/David-Lor/MQTT2NotifySend/blob/master/mqtt2notifysend.sh, and publish your notifications with mosquitto_pub

Answer (score 0):

Install `rsyslog`, earmark a server as a central logging server, update `rsyslog.conf` on clients to forward the syslog to the central server. Then do the processing there.

Or you could modify syslog's `syslog.conf` to forward critical messages to named pipes and as soon as there is something in the named pipe, do something with / email it.

```
#syslog.conf
...
*.crit |/PipeCriticalMessages
...
```

Then you might have a process that consumes the data in the pipe or feed it to an ingest platform [e.g. `Apache's Flume` if you'll have large amounts of data].